# Adding outlets to UIButton

Tags: iphone, cocoa, interface-builder, uibutton

For quickly mocking up UI, I'd like to be able to drag buttons onto a view in interface builder, then drag a connection from that button to the view that should appear when you click it.

A subclass of UIButton is a little inconvenient to use in IB, so I'd prefer to add the behavior to UIButton itself. Unfortunately, it seems like outlets created in a category aren't visible in IB:

```
@interface UIButton (myextensions) {
    IBOutlet UIView *outletDestination;
}
@end
```

Can extra outlets be added this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can extra outlets be added this way?

Nope. You can't add instance variables by declaring them in a category.

You can, however, add properties, and you can put `IBOutlet` on properties, so you can add outlets that way. With the modern runtime (the only one available on the iPhone), properties can add instance variables.

I don't think you can do this if you intend to make a custom accessor for the property (you must use `@synthesize`), but it doesn't sound like this matters for your case: You're just mocking up UI, so you're not going to write custom accessors.

Alternatively, you can create outlets in IB itself on the Classes tab of the Library panel. Select a class there, then the Outlets tab in the pane below, then add an outlet to the list.

You'll need to have a nib open for that other solution, or no classes will show up. That's because it's context-sensitive: A Mac nib will have AppKit classes (like NSButton), whereas an iPhone nib will have UIKit classes.

Comment: If I add a @property to a UIButton category, I can't use @synthesize because it's a category, and I can't write my own methods because there's no ivar to store the data in. If I create the outlet in IB, "[<UIRoundedRectButton 0x391d5f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key destination." I tried all the above with UIRoundedRectButton, too.

Comment: Adding outlets in IB is only really useful for mocking up; when you get down to actually programming, you can and should declare the outlets in the headers. What do you mean “I can't use `@synthesize`”? What happens when you try?

Comment: I'm sorry I missed your comment; I don't think I got an e-mail notification. The error for using @synthesize is this: "@synthesize not allowed in a category's implementation"

Comment: alltom: Huh. You're right. Sorry for the wrong path. I guess you'd have to implement a custom accessor using associative references in place of ivars, but the documentation seems to suggest that that feature is not available in Cocoa Touch yet. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/articles/ocAssociativeReferences.html

Comment: That would be what I want! Ah, well.